# Nagios Check NRPE and Executing scripts show different outputs

Tags: linux, nagios, nrpe

When executing a script through check_nrpe and executing it from local server displays two different out puts.

Script is similar to this.

```
url="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5000/v2/_catalog";
status="$(curl --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output /dev/null  $url)"

    if [ "$status" = 200 ]
    then
            echo "OK"
            exit 0
    else
            echo "Not responding.Please check."
            exit 2
    fi
```

When executing this script file from the local server directly it generates the following output

```
[root@xxxxxlibexec]$ ./check.sh 
OK
```

But when I execute this from the Nagios Core server through check_nrpe it generates the else block.

```
[root@xxxxx libexec]# ./check_nrpe -H xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p 5667 -c check_registry
Not responding.Please check.
```

The NRPE CFG command is as follows.

```
command[check_registry]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check.sh
```

I have tried restarting the NRPE and Nagios Core. Also double checked the permission issues.

Comment: From experience, this can be an issue with Selinux not allowing the nrpe daemon from executing the script

Comment: @RamanSailopal Actually the script is executing both ways. But the exit value is different

Comment: Yeah, this is what I mean. Selinux possibly is stopping the initial curl command from executing, Get the script to echo the $status variable back in the output

Comment: @RamanSailopal Yeah the curl returns and empty status.But Selinux is disabled. [root@xxx]# getenforce 
Disabled

Comment: @DinukaKavinda Try switch to NRPE account/user on that server and run it manually like `bash -x /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

This was due to the curl and libcurl mismatch. The nagios user can't curl properly. Downgraded the packages to be the same.